# How do I make my Phaser game shoot more than one arrow?

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, phaser-framework

I'm making an archery game in JavaScript using the Phaser framework. So far I've got where the arrow goes and hits the target, but if you want the arrow to shoot again, you have to reload the page. How do I make it so that it can shoot more than once?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>TSA Video Game</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade'
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update,
            render: render
        }
    };

    //Start the game
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
        this.load.image('archer', 'assets/archer.png');
        this.load.image('target', 'assets/target.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/ground.png');
        this.load.image('rings', 'assets/rings.png');
        this.load.image('arrow', 'assets/arrow.png');

    }

    function create ()
    {   
        //Load all the images
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
        this.add.image(200, 200, 'ground');
        this.add.image(530, 365, 'target');
        this.add.image(300, 100, 'rings');

        //Create the archer/player
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 410, 'archer');
        //Create the arrow to shoot
        this.arrow = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 430, 'arrow');

        //Get keypresses
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        //Assign input for spacebar
        this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

    }

    function update ()
    {   
        //Declare constants for movement
        const moveAmt = 1500;
        const moveYamt = 0;
        this.player.setDrag(2000); 

        //Move the player left or right
        if (this.cursors.right.isDown) 
        this.player.setVelocityX(moveAmt);
        if (this.cursors.left.isDown)
        this.player.setVelocityX(-moveAmt);

        //Rotation of the player
        if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.player.angle > -45) {
            this.player.angle -= 1;}
        if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.player.angle < 0) {
            this.player.angle += 1;}

        //Shooting with the spacebar
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)) {
            this.arrow.setVelocityX(moveAmt);
            this.arrow.setVelocityY(moveYamt);
        }

        //Stop the arrow once it hits the bullseye
        if (this.arrow.x > 480) {
            this.arrow.x = 480;
            this.arrow.setVelocityX(0);
            this.arrow.setVelocityY(0);
        }

    }

    function render() {
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried creating three arrows, and nesting another if statement inside the "if (Phaser.Keyboard.Justdown" statement, but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to create an array of objects. Each object contains all the information needed for that one arrow.

Comment: @Intervalia what would that look like? You don’t have to write it for me but could you give an example? Would I have to paste the code for the arrow for however many arrows I wanted to have?

Answer (score 3):

You need to be able to create an Array of arrows.

This is a quick, get-you-going, example:

In your `create()` function

`this.arrows = [];` // Create your array

And later:

```
if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)) {
  let arrow = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 430, 'arrow'); // Create a new arrow
  arrow.setVelocityX(moveAmt); // get it moving
  arrow.setVelocityY(moveYamt);
  this.arrows.push(arrow); // save it in the array
}
```

Yes you need much more code, but this should help.

Then you need to cycle through the arrows that are in motion and update each of them

Comment: Actually Phaser has a class for this, called `Phaser.Group` check out https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=game%20objects/group/&q=  or maybe one of these games uses it  -> https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=games/&q=